# How to differentiate the request from Web View or normal browser

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net

We have developed a HTML5 application. We have to show the application in both the normal browser and in the iphone web view. We have done the implementation for the webview. Now we just want to differentiate whether the request is coming from the normal browser or webview. Any solution in c# .net or javascript

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look into  [Request.Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx) property

Hope this helps